# Finding Value With CSS Selector After Defined Text

Tags: dom, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm using DOM Element variable type in Google Tag Manager to select text values to store into tracking codes via CSS Selector.  However, I am stuck on trying to select the right CSS Selector value as there are 15 with the same values and the only way to distinguish the value I want, is it proceeds a specific text value.

using document.querySelectorAll and other queries to strip out the rest of the values, but I can't figure it out.

This is the HTML:

```
<span class="vdp-info-data col-sm-9 col-xs-9"><span class="vdp-info-label">Interior Color</span> <span class="vdp-info-value">Black</span></span></li><li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<span class="vdp-info-data col-sm-9 col-xs-9"><span class="vdp-info-label">Body Style</span> <span class="vdp-info-value">Coupe</span></span></li><li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
```

I'm looking to grab the text "Couple" through Google Tag Manager DOM Element, or one of the other variables to then push back to Google for tracking.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are on the right path, but unfortunately have reached the end of what CSS selectors can provide. There is no ":contains(text)" CSS selector (it was proposed but never implemented).

Second, although this makes it not possible to grab the value with the "DOM Element" variable, you can still grab it using a "Custom JavaScript" Page Variable. With JavaScript, you could either use document.querySelectorAll() and then filter to find the label and then use sibling to get the value, like this: [image]

```
function(){
    var bodyStyle;
    var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.vdp-info-label');
    for (var x=0; x<labels.length; x++){
        if(labels[x].innerText.trim()==='Body Style'){
            bodyStyle = labels[x].nextElementSibling.innerText;
            // Or use labels[x].parentElement.querySelector('.vdp-info-value').innerText
            break;
        }
    };
    return bodyStyle;
}
```

Or, you could grab the parent element that contains all the label-value combinations for the car, and use regex to extract the value of interest.

#### Sidenote

I noticed it looks like you are trying to scrape vehicle attributes of a dealer's vehicle page. You might want to check if they are placing vehicle details in another spot in the page that is easier to scrape, such as a schema section or global JS variables (both are common on templated dealer sites).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Yes, this is data from a car dealership website, however there is no scheme setup for the vehicle type, only the top level details such as year make and model.